# Changing Materializecss select text colors

Tags: vue.js, materialize

I'm using Materaliizecss select in two separate vue.js components. In one component I want the select text color to be white, the other component I want the select text color to be black.

In the first component's style I can change the select text color to white by using this css

```
.select-dropdown{
  color:white;
}
```

Unfortunately, this makes the select text color white in both components! So in my second component's I've placed this css

```
.select-dropdown{
  color: black;
}
```

Now both component's select text colors are black.

If I add "scoped" to the style tag the .select-dropdown css seems to be ignored.

Any suggestions as to how to change the Materaliizecss select text color in one component such that it does not affect other components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a little Materialize theory:

```
// Color of the chosen item

.select-dropdown{
  color: firebrick;
}

// color of the dropdown options

.dropdown-content li>a, .dropdown-content li>span {
    color: firebrick;
}
```

Now, we need to be more specific to target an individual `select`. I like to put a classname on the `input-field` that wraps the select - Materialize doesn't use the native `select`, it hides it and replaces it with a `text-input` and `dropdown` - so adding class names to the select itself wouldn't work:

```
<div class="blue-select input-field">
    <select></select>
</div>

// Add a class to the wrapping input-field

.input-field.blue-select .select-dropdown{
  color: steelblue;
}

.input-field.blue-select .dropdown-content li>a,
.input-field.blue-select .dropdown-content li>span {
    color: steelblue;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/wvGwrWM).